Vue JS change to-be-edited variable depending on parameter passed into function
Hi JS (and general) newbie here,
I'm currently trying to make simple webpage with Vue JS which has clickable content which results in that section expanding to reveal more content.
I did this with a boolean variable expanded which gets toggled on-click.
<q-card @click="expand_header()">
<div v-show="expanded">

export default {
  setup() {
    return {
      expanded: ref(false),
    };
  },
}

expand_header: function () {

      this.expanded = !this.expanded;

    },

However, because I am trying to add this functionality to multiple boxes, I wanted to abstract this functionality and pass a parameter when the function is called which will edit the corresponding variable, and I was wondering what the correct syntax would be.
Newbie instincts told me to pass a number parameter into the function which will edit one of similar variables like so:
@click="expand_header(1)"
@click="expand_header(2)"
<div v-show="expanded1">content<div>
<div v-show="expanded2">content<div>
export default {
  setup() {
    return {
      expanded1: ref(false),
      expanded2: ref(false),
    };
  },
}

expand_header: function (num) {

      this.expanded[num] = !this.expanded[num];

    },

or so:
expand_header: function (num) {

      this.expanded + num = !this.expanded + num;

    },

however this is clearly not the correct syntax.
I was not sure where I could find documentation or guides on JS syntax for this type of problem, so any input or document recommendation would be greatly appreciated!

Just create a component for the cards like that (use a slot for the content (you can add a named slot for the header):
Playground
<script>
import {ref} from 'vue';
export default{
  props:{
    title: String
  },
  setup(){
    return {
      expanded: ref(false)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="q-card" @click="expanded = !expanded">
    {{ title }}
  </div>
  <div v-if="expanded" class="content">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

Usage:
<script>
  import Section from './Section.vue';
  export default {
    components: {Section},
    setup() {
      return {
        components: {Section},
      };
    },
  }
</script>

<template>
  <Section title="Section 1">
    Section 1 content
  </Section>
  <Section title="Section 2">
    Section 2 content
  </Section>
</template>



Thanks for this! This seems like a neater way of implementing my desired functionality, though I'm going to have to play around with your code a little bit, as I don't fully understand what is going on.
I do still wonder whether there is a correct version of my attempt at implementing this, as I was able to get it to work in python.

@MichaelRosenke if this will solve your problem don't hesitate to accept it (the gray checkbox), this is how stackoverflow works, thanks
